# Когда нужно фильтровать данные?

Tags: php

Когда использовать htmlspecialchars и strip_tags при внесении данных в таблицу или при выводе? Почему?

Я считаю, что при выводе, потому что данные в таблице может кто-то изменить, а при выводе мы исключаем проблему. Но если использовать при выводе, то падает скорость.

Как лучше? Почему?

Comment: > Я считаю, что при выводе, потому что данные в таблице может кто-то изменить, а при выводе мы исключаем проблему. Но если использовать при выводе, то падает скорость.

эм, что?

Comment: @Etki. Например, мы вносим данные в таблицу и обрабатываем их функцией htmlspecialchars. Когда мы выводим данные с таблицы мы ничего не делаем. Если кто-то получит доступ к таблице, то он может изменить данные и создать одну из уязвимостей. А если мы обрабатываем данные после получения из таблицы, то мы исключаем такую проблему. Как лучше?

Comment: @muwumelalo, если кто-то получил доступ к вашей БД, вывод данных - это последнее, что вас должно волновать.

Comment: @andreyqin так фильтровать после получения из базы или при вставке? (речь о sql-инъекциям не идет)

Comment: @muwumelalo, фильтруйте при выводе. Но причина не та, что вы описали выше, просто данные лучше хранить в том виде, в котором они пришли, если, конечно, это не угрожает безопасности и нет необходимости в каком-то специальном форматированном выводе.

Comment: @andreyqin а в чем причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с бд предназначены специальные функции mysql_real_escape_string() - для текста и abs(intval()) - для чисел.

htmlspecialchars() и stripslashes - для вывода текста

Comment: @muwumelalo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).